# How to change delay of a certain image in slider?

Tags: javascript, plugins, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/).
How to increase delay for the first element only?
Slides are output dynamically like this:

```
{foreach $alldata as $item}
            {if !empty($item->url)}
                <a href="{$item->url}"
                   class="main-promo__slider-slide swiper-slide"
                   style="background-image: url('/storage/slider/{$item->img}')"
                   target="_blank">
                    {if !empty($item->mintext) || !empty($item->title)}
                        <div class="main-promo__slider-slide-content">
                            {if !empty($item->title)}
                                <p class="main-promo__slider-slide-title">{$item->title}</p>
                            {/if}
                            {if !empty($item->mintext)}
                                <p class="main-promo__slider-slide-text">{$item->mintext|truncate:200}</p>
                            {/if}
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                </a>
            {else}
            .........
        {/foreach}
    {/if}
</div>
```

According to docs you can do it like this:

```
<div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="2000">
```

But how to implement it in my case?